# Unwanted right-side space in JQuery slideToggle() animation on Chrome

Tags: jquery

I try to write a simple menu with JQuery slideToggle().

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn-nav">Navigation</button>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, I find that if float the button to left. There is an unwanted space at the right side of the menu on Chrome.

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/wenjiehu/agcnsako/ on Chrome for a demo of this bug. Try to click the "navigation" button and see what happens on the right side of the menu.

Actually, this can be fixed by wrap a .clearfix div to the float button. See http://jsfiddle.net/wenjiehu/agcnsako/2/ . But for some reason I can't wrap this additional `<div>`.

Could someone help me find another solution?

**Update:**

@Dipaks: the paddings and negative margins are exactly what I needed. Can't remove them.

Comment: Removing the paddings and margins gives you expected result

Answer (score 0):

Comment the minus margins and remove `.btn-nav` class - they are not needed

```
.menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    /* margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px; 
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;*/
}
```

[**Check updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/agcnsako/5/)